# MacOS High Sierra MySQL5.7 server has gone away, multi-connect not possible?

Tags: mysql, magento, macos-high-sierra

I am running MySQL 5.7 on MacOS High Sierra.

I mainly use it for hosting Magento websites locally for programming/debugging. I also use Sequel Pro to make changes when necessary also locally.

My first "MySQL Server has gone away" issue occured when I left Sequal Pro connected, and I attempted to load the webshop. The webpage could not load. As far as my website was concerned, the server was offline. That was of course not true, once I quit Sequel Pro everything resumed to work correctly.

Very recently I noticed that I am not able to login to the admin panel and refresh the front-page at the same time. I am unable to send more than two requests to the database. If I am loading a certain page, and it is currently busy reading from the database, then I cannot send another database query request/connection

I could not find a post that explained the issue like this, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I hope someone has experienced this and perhaps can give me some advice on how to fix this annoyance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a solution to this issue myself, but since I installed the database using the official MySQL website, I took a step back and decided to try to setup MySQL using Homebrew instead.

Now everything is working correctly, and I can have multiple connections to the database simultaneously. Consequently, I indeed needed to re-import every database.